# Javascript Char Codes - Key Code 0

Tags: javascript, validation, keycode

I have an `input field` in `thymeleaf HTML` with number validation in `javascript`, according to my research, there is several ways, how to do it.

One of them:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
         if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                   return false;
        }
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The question: What is 0 in first if statement?

According to [this](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) key code 8 is backspace and numbers between 48 - 57 are numbers (i.e.: 1,2,3,...,9).

Comment: Have you tried to see the commit details that added it?

Comment: The code was just copy & paste from web. There were no details about 0 key code, just this little script to handle input validation. which is ok. I was just curious about 0.

Comment: [e.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is obsolete, don't use it.

Comment: @Teemu, not sure if that applies to the jQuery event property with the same name (which is used in the OP). The [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) even say *"It is recommended to watch `event.which` for keyboard key input."*. Do you have more info on this?

Comment: @trincot Actually no, I just didn't notice, that it was a jQuery event property used here. Though looking at the source, it seems that jQuery 3.2.1 returns `event.charCode` or `eventKeyCode` if `event.which` is not available. All of these properties are deprecated/obsolete ...

Comment: @Teemu, interesting! Keeps one wondering why jQuery still advocates its use instead of pointing to the `e.key` property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the `keypress` event, the value 0 is given for most of the keys that do not produce a character. Exceptions exist, such as backspace. Also, the actual codes are implementation (incl. hardware) dependent.

When `e.which` is zero, the code may assume that no printable character is being generated, and so there is no reason to block it. This is useful especially for arrow and soft keys: you'll want to allow the user to move the caret with left and right keys, possibly together with <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Nor would you want to block the user from refreshing the page with <kbd>F5</kbd>, or deleting a character with <kbd>Del</kbd>, or to move to the next input field with <kbd>Tab</kbd>. All of those keys come with `e.which` equal to 0.

However, the script is not perfect. For instance, it does not allow the user to use clipboard handling shortcuts, such as <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

In general it is not advised to block input keys like that, as you don't want the user to think their keyboard is stuck. Better is to allow the keys to render the corresponding characters, but (only) indicate via visual clues that the input is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

It means the JS engine doesn't recognize the key, thus this code is ensuring that the key is identifiable.

> Implementations that are unable to identify a key use the key value 0.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#dom-keyboardevent-keycode